# Change UIButton highlighted image in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to change a `UIImage` in a `UIButton`, when highlighted. The `UIButton` is situated in a `UINavigationController`.

I have the following code:

```
UIView *containingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 28)];
UIButton *barUIButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[barUIButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
barUIButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
barUIButton.frame = CGRectMake(-9, 0, 28, 28);
[barUIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[barUIButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AddHighlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
[containingView addSubview:barUIButton];
UIBarButtonItem *containingBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:containingView] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = containingBarButton;
```

Instead of the new image showing when highlighted, there is just a black shadow around the existing image.

Why is this?

Comment: When working with `png` files and `imageNamed:`, you don't have to specify the file extension. `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add"]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `UIButton` instance isn't getting highlighted or selected on the touch down event. This is probably because `UIBarButtonItem` instances don't act like normal buttons; in fact, they're not even UIButton `subclasses`.

There is a workaround. If you keep a reference to your `UIButton` in an instance variable, you can add code to change the button's image:

```
[barUIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[barUIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUp];
```

In `pressDown:` and `pressUp:`, you can set the

```
-(void)pressDown:(id)sender
{
    [barUIButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

And similarly for `pressUp:`.

Comment: This works, although the black glow just appears over the new image. How can I stop the default UIBarButtonItem black glow?

Comment: I'm not sure that you'll be able to - the glow is part of the `UIBarButtonItem` and probably can't be configured.